# AWS elasticsearch service with open access

Tags: aws-elasticsearch

I have this template that was working till February.

https://datameetgeobk.s3.amazonaws.com/cftemplates/EyeOfCustomer_updated.yaml.txt

Something related to Fine Grained access changed and I get the error...

> Enable fine-grained access control or apply a restrictive access
> policy to your domain (Service: AWSElasticsearch; Status Code: 400;
> Error Code: ValidationException

This is just a test server and I do not want to protect it using Advanced security options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you receive is because Amazon enabled the fine grained access control as part of its [release in February 2020](https://github.com/awsdocs/amazon-elasticsearch-service-developer-guide/blob/master/doc_source/release-notes.md).
You can enable VPCOptions for the cluster and create a subnet + security group and allow access through that security group. Add VPC ID as a parameter say pVpc (default VPC in thise case)

1. Add vpc parameter

```
  pVpc:
    Description: VPC ID
    Type: String
    Default: default-xxadssad - your default vpc id
```

2. Add subnet & security group

```
ESSubnetA:
  Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
  Properties:
    VpcId:
      Ref: !Ref pVpc
    AvailabilityZone: ${self:provider.region}a
    CidrBlock: !Ref pVpcCIDR
    Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: es-subneta

ESSecurityGroup:
  Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
  Properties:
    GroupDescription: SecurityGroup for Elasticsearch
    VpcId:
      Ref: !Ref pVpc
    SecurityGroupIngress: 
      - FromPort: '443' 
        IpProtocol: tcp 
        ToPort: '443' 
        CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
    Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: es-sg
```

3. Enable VPCOptions

```
    VPCOptions: 
      SubnetIds: 
        - !Ref ESSubnetA
      SecurityGroupIds: 
        - !Ref ESSecurityGroup
```

Comment: but what if i want to not use the VPC and just use public access. Also fine grained access control does not work with some instance types, so is there any other option other than upgrading your instance type ( from t2.small.elasticsearch to something else )